# Why does spark-shell fail with "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."?

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I have installed Spark in my local machine(Windows). After installation, when I try to type : **spark-shell** I am getting following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Got to know there may be a chance that there is **multiple JRE's** installed or **JAVA_HOME** indicates wrong installation path.But when I checked it seems all perfect.

Here is my java installation directory:

```
>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe
```

Here is my path:

> JAVA_HOME :  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with typing `spark`

Comment: It's `spark-shell`

Comment: when i typed spark-shell, i got following error:  >spark-shell
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

That's the "beauty" of Windows OS and its integration with Java.

The error is because you installed JDK and Spark to directories with spaces in their paths. That surely happens for Java as defined by `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

**IMPORTANT** Make sure to install winutils.exe and define `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Hi @Jacek, I am facing a similar issue but i don't have any spaces in the path. I see that the path is wrong but i am not able to figure out from where it is picking the incorrect path `'C:\\C:\\Users\\xyz\\opt\\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.3.3.jar'`. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dileep_Gog I'd recommend asking a separate question.